# Criar nova matriz com conteúdos de outra matriz

Tags: java

Matriz principal:

```
public static String [][] matrizPrincipal(){
     String [] [] matriz = new String [2] [6];
     matriz[0][0] = "Robin Arryn";
     matriz[0][1] = "Lino Facioli";
     matriz[0][2] = "145";
     matriz[0][3] = "Vivo";
     matriz[0][4] = "Arryn";
     matriz[0][5] = "Feminino";

     matriz[1][0] = "Yohn Royce";
     matriz[1][1] = "Rupert Vansittart";
     matriz[1][2] = "45";
     matriz[1][3] = "Vivo";
     matriz[1][4] = "Arryn";
     matriz[1][5] = "Feminino";
     return matriz;
}
```

Método que caso o personagem (coluna *0* da matriz principal) for uma mulher (coluna *5*) e pertencer a família *Arryn* (coluna *4*) adiciona o nome desse personagem a uma nova matriz:

```
public static void imprimeMatrizFeminina(String [] [] mat){
     int cont = 0;
     //Método para Mulheres da família Arryn
     for(int i=0; i<mat.length; i++){
        if(mat[i][5].equals("Feminino") && mat[i][4].equals("Arryn")) cont ++;
     }
     String[] matrizFemininaArryn = new String [cont];

     for(int i=0; i<mat.length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<matrizFemininaArryn.length; j++){
           if(mat[i][5].equals("Feminino") && mat[i][4].equals("Arryn")){
               matrizFemininaArryn[j] = mat[i][0];
           }
        }    
     }
     System.out.println("Mulheres da família Arryn em ordem alfabética crescente:" + Arrays.toString(matrizFemininaArryn));
}
```

Porém ao testar, ele retorna somente o primeiro personagem (*Robin Arryn*) e a segunda posição retorna **nulo** ao invés do nome *Yohn Royce*.

Imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse problema acontece porque no método `imprimeMatrizFeminina` você itera *n* vezes sobre a *array* `matrizFemininaArryn`, o que é desnecessário, retire o terceiro `for` e use a variável `j` como índice:

```
public static void imprimeMatrizFeminina(String [] [] mat){
    int cont = 0, j = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < mat.length; i++)
       if(mat[i][5].equals("Feminino") && mat[i][4].equals("Arryn")) cont ++;

    String[] matrizFemininaArryn = new String [ cont ];

    for(int i = 0; i < mat.length; i++){
        if(mat[i][5].equals("Feminino") && mat[i][4].equals("Arryn")){
            matrizFemininaArryn[j] = mat[i][0];
            j ++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Mulheres da família Arryn em ordem alfabética crescente:" + Arrays.toString(matrizFemininaArryn));
}
```

[Ver `demonstração`](http://ideone.com/TSJEDA)

Alternativamente, você pode utilizar uma [lista](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html):

```
public static void imprimeMatrizFeminina(String [] [] mat){
    List<String> matrizFemininaArryn = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i = 0; i < mat.length; i++){
        if(mat[i][5].equals("Feminino") && mat[i][4].equals("Arryn")){
            matrizFemininaArryn.add(mat[i][0]);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Mulheres da família Arryn em ordem alfabética crescente: " + matrizFemininaArryn);
}
```

[Ver `demonstração`](http://ideone.com/gDi8J1)

Comment: Excelente! Era isso mesmo ! Muito obrigado xD